# What's causing my array to be filled with unwanted numbers

Tags: c, arrays, adt, realloc

I am trying to implement a set ADT using dynamic arrays. I have a set for odd and even numbers. When a array is full I use realloc to get a bigger array.
The problem is that this also seems to fill the array with unwanted numbers.

```
struct set
{
    void **array;
    int numitems;
    int maxitems;
    cmpfunc_t cmpfunc;
};
```

.

```
void set_add(set_t *set, void *elem)
{
    if (!set_contains(set, elem))
    {
        if (set->numitems + 1 >= set->maxitems) // Make new bigger array if full
        {
            void **new_array = realloc(set->array, sizeof(void *) * set->maxitems * 2);
            if (new_array == NULL)
                printf("Error");
            set->maxitems *= 2;
            set->array = new_array;
        }
        set->array[set->numitems] = elem;
        set->numitems++;
    }
}
```

In main i use this to add numbers.

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        set_add(evens, numbers[i]);
    else
    {
        printset("Odd numbers":, odds);
        set_add(odds, numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the output I get.

Output:

- Odd numbers: 1
- Odd numbers: 1 3
- Odd numbers: 1 3 5

...

- Odd numbers: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29
- Odd numbers: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31
- Odd numbers: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
- Odd numbers: 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

...

After 31 is added, the array maxsize (=16) is doubled. Any ideas what causes the rest of the array to be filled? This is just a small part of the code, so if nothing here seems to be the cause I can post more.

=== Addition info: ===

```
static void printset(char *prefix, set_t *set)
{
    set_iter_t *it;

    printf("%s", prefix);
    it = set_createiter(set);
    while (set_hasnext(it)) {
        int *p = set_next(it);
        printf(" %d", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");
    set_destroyiter(it);
}
```

.

```
set_iter_t *set_createiter(set_t *set)
{
    set_iter_t *iter = malloc(sizeof(set_iter_t));
    if (iter == NULL)
        return NULL;
    bobsort(set);
    iter->set = set;
    iter->cur = 0;

    return iter;
}

int set_hasnext(set_iter_t *iter)
{
    if (iter->set->array[iter->cur] == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

void *set_next(set_iter_t *iter)
{
    if (iter->set->array[iter->cur] == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        void *elem = iter->set->array[iter->cur];
        iter->cur++;
        return elem;
    }
}
```

It's for an assignment, so I'm following the function signatures. I'm used to make adt list with linked list and not arrays.

Comment: How do you print the array?

Comment: The indentation does not prevent `set_add(odds, numbers[i]);` being called unconditionally. The `else` code block needs `{` braces `}`.

Comment: Why are you using `void**` as a datatype here for what appears to be a 2D array? How are you using this code? Also as Weather Vane points out, it may be in your best interest to *always* use the `{ ... }` braces on an `if` statement to avoid the mistake you've made here.

Comment: There is also the possibility that `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` in `main()` breaks the array upper bound of `numbers[]` although there is not enough code posted to be sure.

Comment: the else braces was a typo only here and not in the code.

Comment: @Terrowin that is one reason why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is asked for. You posted a rag-bag of disconnected code with typos that cannot be compiled and run. Also the *act* of preparing the MCVE can tip you off as to where the problem is. By the time you correct typos and explain what is missing, commenters might have lost interest and moved on.

Comment: What's `n`? What's `numbers`? What's `set_iter_t`? Why is `set_add` looking at the counters while `set_hasnext` is looking at the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `set_add` you should change the `if` condition:

```
 if (set->numitems + 1 >= set->maxitems) // Make new bigger array if full
```

to

```
if (set->numitems  >= set->maxitems) // Make new bigger array if full
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the definition of realloc():  The contents will be unchanged in the range from the start of the region up to the minimum of the old and new sizes. If the new size is larger than the old size, **the added memory will not be initialized**.
So I believe you shouldn't use if (iter->set->array[iter->cur] == NULL) in set_hasnext(set_iter_t *iter) as you didn't initialize the re-allocate array to NULL. In another word, the value in the array may be random.

Comment: I don't think this work either. Since you know how many elements in your set by visiting set->numitems, you can just print them with a for loop with n<=set->numitems.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 two changes that fix my issue:

In add_set(), change

```
if (set->numitems + 1 >= set->maxitems)
```

to

```
if (set->numitems  >= set->maxitems)
```

And in set_hasnext(), change

```
if (iter->set->array[iter->cur] == NULL)
```

to

```
if (iter->cur >= iter->set->numitems)
```

Thanks to Tran and Anthony.